# ListView not refreshing properly on ArrayAdapter & AsyncTask

Tags: android-listview, android-asynctask, refresh, android-arrayadapter

I have searched almost all website to understand how to refresh the listview, but somehow still the refresh is not working properly & my app is crashing after sometime. Functonality: My App is getting values from web(odata)server & printing it in listview properly. But when I am trying to refresh it:nothing works. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.. Any help is appreciated..
Please find my code below..

```
MainActivity.java:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button call;static boolean running=true;
    ListView list; ArrayList categories;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        call = (Button) findViewById (R.id.mybtn);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
        categories = new ArrayList();

        call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto- generated method stub
            new callService().execute(); 
                }
        });
    }
    public class callService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if(running){
       ODataConsumer c =    ODataJerseyConsumer.create("http://x.x.x.x/CCTickerService/CCTickerService.svc/");      
       List<OEntity> listEntities = c.getEntities("LatestExchRates").filter("ExchangeID eq 21 and FutureYear eq 2006 and FutureMonth eq 7").execute().toList();
       if (listEntities.size() > 0) {
       for (OEntity entity : listEntities) {categories.add("\nExId-  "+entity.getProperty("ExchangeID").getValue().toString()+"   Last "+entity.getProperty("Last").getValue().toString()+"  Open-"+entity.getProperty("Open").getValue().toString());}
             }
       }
       return categories;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        //  TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
       //CODE TO REFRESH EVERY 25 SECOND    
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
   @Override
       public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 25*1000 );
            new callService().execute();
            categories.clear();
            adapter.addAll(categories);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.invalidateViews();
                }
            }, 25*1000 );
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to stop the async task(by clean(true)). But that also didnt work. Issue is: For 1st 2-3 times the data is getting updated in 25s but later the execution becomes v.fast & values are not displaying properly and then app is crashing. Please let me know if I can take some other alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the issue. This is happened because of:
"**handler.postDelayed(this, 25*1000 )**;" 
After commenting it code is working fine.

The above statement makes the code to get into loop again.. & hence corrupt the loop.:)